# Unity disappeared, logged into the "debug mode" only, after cleaning

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

After following this [tutorial](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nettoyer_ubuntu) (without having cleaned everything), I've a huge problem with Unity (last updated version of Ubuntu).

I guess it's this line (but not sure):  `sudo dpkg-P`dpkg-l | grep" ^ rc "| tr-s '' | cut-d ''-f 2

So, I can not boot Ubuntu at all, I have a black screen BEFORE the login screen. I'm logging with the "debug mode", but I do not have unity or the taskbar.

This is really problematic. I no longer have access to the list of programs, or anything once, because not "user interface"

I did an **apt-get update and upgrade**, or **unity --reset**, or re-install Unity, but nothing changes.

Thank you for your help.

Fabrice

Comment: This should be moved to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). That's what the close vote is really for, but Ask Ubuntu was not an option in the "off topic" sub-dialog.